# Declare a global variable using an external module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript1.7

I'm authoring an npm module in TypeScript https://www.npmjs.com/package/html2commonmark. The module can be used in nodejs (by using `require`) and from the browser (by loading `node_modules/html2commonmark/dist/client/bundle.js` in your browser).

I've recently added the *.d.ts files in order to get typing information when using `"moduleResolution": "node"`. This works great, when installing my module it is ready to be used in typescript. Thus: the following piece of typescript code is compiling without errors:

```
// After installing using npm install html2commonmark
// using "moduleResolution": "node"
import * as html2commonmark from 'html2commonmark';
let converter = new html2commonmark.JSDomConverter();
```

Beautiful!

Now i want to run my module in a browser. As mentioned before, i need to add a script tag to `node_modules/html2commonmark/dist/client/bundle.js` to my index.html page. After that, the html2commonmark global variable should be available. The problem is: how do i let the typescript compile know that the global variable is there? The following piece of TS code won't compile:

```
let converter = new html2commonmark.BrowserConverter(); 
// error TS2304: Cannot find name 'html2commonmark'.
```

Even if i add a global.d.ts file, I don't seem to be able to both import my external module and declare my global variable:

```
// Something like this does not work :(
import * as b from 'html2commonmark';
declare var html2commonmark: typeof b;
```

I understand why this is. By using the import keyword my ts file is converted to an external module and thus needs to be imported. Yet i feel like my scenario is a common one. Namely: an npm module containing both an npm component and the bundle for the browser which exposes the functionality as a global variable.

Is there any way to declare the global variable using the definition inside my external module? I don't feel like rewriting my api as a (DefinitelyTyped-style) namespace while i just written my entire source code in TS...

Answer (score 2):

The correct ways to write an external module that works in both a browser and in Node.js is:

1. Use the `--module umd` flag and then use an AMD loader in the browser to load the module
2. Use the `--module commonjs` flag and then use a bundler like webpack or browserify

In other words, when you start writing modular code, blindly adding `<script>` tags to an HTML file is no longer the correct way to load that code into a browser. Just as you should not touch the global scope in Node.js, so too should you not touch the global scope in a browser. You could hack it with a `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') (<any>window).global = yourObject;`, but seriously, **don’t ever do this, it is wrong and it will break**.

<del>As far as exposing interfaces from within external modules to a global scope, there is no way to do this, since you would have to `import` the external module to get a reference to its interfaces, at which point you’ve created another external module.</del> As of TypeScript 1.8, you can augment global types from inside modules by using [`declare global`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation).

Comment: Thanks for your response! To produce the bundle.js i'm using webpack. Of course, i could also force (typescript) consumers writing for the browser to use webpack/browserify. I was just wondering if there was a better way. I feel like it should be possible.

using `(<any>window).global = yourObject` is not needed, because the object already is available on the global scope (at least: when including the bundje.js on your page). I'm just looking for a way to make it visible to typescript.

Comment: In that case, the answer is a much simpler “no” :) You can expose global interfaces to named modules in hand-written d.ts files by `declare module "foo" { export = SomeGlobal; }`, but there is no way to go in the other direction.

Comment: That is too bad. If you update your answer with the short version i'll mark it as the correct answer

Comment: You are my hero: `if (typeof window !== 'undefined') (<any>window).global = yourObject;` ;-)